# How to update angularjs constant during run time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constants

I have defined constant in my application as follows,

```
angular.module('configuration', [])
 .constant('Engine_API', 'http://sample.io:1929/')
```

And i am using in the application as follows,

```
var testApp = angular.module('Duot', [ 'configuration']
testApp .controller('userProfileCtrl', function ($scope,Engine_API) {
}
```

is there a way i can modify and set a new value to the constant in run time?

Comment: Kindof by definition, given that it is a constant, you cannot.

Comment: If you are looking for easy updatable central storage, consider using a `value`. `.value('myData', { Engine_API: 'http://sample.io:1929/' });` You can then access and update `myData.Engine_API` as desired.

Comment: Why you not create a dataservice to share some general data?

Comment: Constants are great for values that never change

Comment: or use a provider which you can set at run time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change angular constant value. But if you want to change value, you can use angular value provider instead of constant.

```
angular.module('configuration', [])
 .value('Engine_API', 'http://sample.io:1929/')
```